# Trouble with CSV formatting

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

Having problems with formatting CSV created from C# code. In the notepad file the output scrolls vertically down one row (the values seen in the structs below are output in one row. There is a row of numbers as well that appears directly below the struct values but the numbers should be in a new row beside the structs). When I open in excel it's a similar story only the output from the structs is where it should be however the row of numbers appears directly below the struct values but one row to the right if that makes sense, and the numbers should appear directly beside their corresponding struct values. The code I'm using is below.

Here are the structs for the dictionaries im working with.

```
public enum Genders
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other,
    UnknownorDeclined,
}

public enum Ages
{
    Upto15Years,
    Between16to17Years,
    Between18to24Years,
    Between25to34Years,
    Between35to44Years,
    Between45to54Years,
    Between55to64Years,
    Between65to74Years,
    Between75to84Years,
    EightyFiveandOver,
    UnavailableorDeclined,
}
```

the csv file that does the outputting using a streamwriter and stringbuilder.

```
public void CSVProfileCreate<T>(Dictionary<T, string> columns, Dictionary<T, int> data)
{
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("c:/temp/testoutputprofile.csv");
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var pair in columns)
        {
            //output.Append(pair.Key);
            //output.Append(",");
            output.Append(pair.Value);
            output.Append(",");
            output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            //output.Append(pair.Key);
            output.Append(",");
            output.Append(d.Value);
            output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        write.Write(output);
        write.Dispose();
}
```

And finally the method to feed the dictionaries into the csv creator.

```
    public void RunReport()
    {
        CSVProfileCreate(genderKeys, genderValues);
        CSVProfileCreate(ageKeys, ageValues);
    }
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I fixed it by doing this:

```
    public void CSVProfileCreate<T>(Dictionary<T, string> columns, Dictionary<T, int> data)
    {
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("c:/temp/testoutputprofile.csv");
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        IEnumerable<string> col = columns.Values.AsEnumerable();
        IEnumerable<int> dat = data.Values.AsEnumerable();

        for (int i = 0; i < col.Count(); i++)
        {
            output.Append(col.ElementAt(i));
            output.Append(",");
            output.Append(dat.ElementAt(i));
            output.Append(",");
            output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        write.Write(output);
        write.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write Environment.NewLine after every single value that you output.

Rather than having two loops, you should have just one loop that outputs

- A "pair"
- A value
- Environment.NewLine

for each iteration.

Assuming `columns` and `data` have the same keys, that could look something like

```
foreach (T key in columns.Keys)
{
    pair = columns[key];
    d = data[key];
    output.Append(pair.Value);
    output.Append(",");
    output.Append(d.Value);
    output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Note two complications:

- If `pair.Value` or `d.Value` contains a comma, you need to surround the output of that cell with double quotes.
- If If `pair.Value` or `d.Value` contains a comma and also contains a double-quote, you have to double up the double-quote to escape it.

Examples:

> Smith, Jr

would have to be output

> "Smith, Jr"

and

> "Smitty" Smith, Jr

would have to be output

> """Smitty"" Smith, Jr"

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment about the keys...

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

If you cannot use the key to associate the right pair with the right data, how *do* you make that association?

If you are iterating the dictionary and they happen to be in the order you hope, that is truly *undefined* behavior that could change with the next .NET service pack.

You need something reliable to relate the pair with the correct data.

**About the var keyword**

*var* is not a type, but rather a shortcut that frees you from writing out the entire type.  You can use *var* if you wish, but the actual type is `KeyValuePair<T, string>` and `KeyValuePair<T, int>` respectively.  You can see that if you write *var* and hover over that keyword with your mouse in Visual Studio.

**About disposing resources**

Your line

```
write.Dispose();
```

is risky.  If any of your code throws an Exception prior to reaching that line, it will never run and *write* will not be disposed.  It is strongly preferable to make use of the *using* keyword like this:

```
using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("c:/temp/testoutputprofile.csv"))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

When the scope of *using* ends (after the associated }), write.Dispose() will be automatically called whether or not an Exception was thrown.  This is the same as, but shorter than,

```
try
{
    StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("c:/temp/testoutputprofile.csv");
    // Your code here
}
finally
{
    write.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: the keys for data and pair are different unfortunately, they're different struct values the key values for pair are from the Genders struct, the key values for d are from the ages struct.

Comment: unless you meant are they the same datatype? in that case yes, they're both enums. Also where are you getting pair and d from? I know where they are in my code but you said not to use 2 foreach statements, so what data type would they be, var?

Comment: A `Dictionary<K,V>` does not guarantee any specific ordering.  See my update to the answer.

Comment: I did the following KeyValuePair<T,string> pair = columns[key];
                KeyValuePair<T,string> d = data[key]; and got an error: cannot implicitly convert type string to systems.collections.generic.keyvaluepair<T,string> the red line appears underneath the columns[key]. Its the same for data but int instead of string.

Comment: Thanks for your help btw, greatly appreciated :), do you know what I need to do for the error I recieved?

Comment: Sorry `KeyValuePair<T, string>` was for the original way you had it coded.  If you are using the single loop, the key is of type `T` in each case and the value is `string` or `int` respectively.  So, you could write `string pair = columns[key]`.  In this case `key` should be of type `T`.  If you do not have the same keys in both dictionaries, though, that approach will not work.